# Easiest way to create a web-based database

Tags: database, database-design

I want to create a simple web-based database where authorized persons can enter following simple data on a web page:

```
ID number: (numeric)
Date: (date)
Plants needed: (text choices from a menu- can be multiple)
```

The data is to be stored on a central server. Authorized persons should also be able to access the information on entering the ID number on a web page. The system should be reasonably secure.

What will be the best way to accompalish this? I know this is a very basic problem but I am a newbie in this area and will appreciate any pointers/help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using HTML, PHP and MySQLi to accomplish this. Using POST data, you can securely relay the clients HTML response to the PHP server end. Without providing further information on what you're actually stuck on, I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any disadvantages of using sqlite3 and phpLiteAdmin?